# c# MailKit how to delete an email from mail server (IMAP)

Tags: c#, mailkit

I've found this:

```
client.Inbox.AddFlags (new int[] { index }, MessageFlags.Deleted);
or
client.Inbox.AddFlags (new UniqueId[] { uid }, MessageFlags.Deleted);

then
client.Inbox.Expunge ();
```

I don't know how to obtain index or uid to use here. My client works like this:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
                client.Connect(serverM.Text, Convert.ToInt32(portM.Text), true);
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH");
                client.Authenticate(user.Text, pass.Text);
                var inbox =  client.GetFolder(inbox.Text);
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
                var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++) // 
                {
                    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
                    ...
                }
}
```

Also int I is not the index. message.MessageID not equal to UID. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 6):

You are using the index here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++) // 
{
    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i);
    ...
}
```

`i` is the index.

In more recent versions of MailKit, I added the ability to do:

```
inbox.AddFlags (i, MessageFlags.Deleted);
```

So now you don't need to do this:

```
inbox.AddFlags (new int[] { i }, MessageFlags.Deleted);
```

Comment: hmmm it removs not readed message, but I read "i" before flaggin to delete

Comment: If you are working with GMail, GMail will move the messages out of the folder once you mark them as \Deleted, so that's probably what you are seeing.

Comment: I should probably point out as well that marking a 1 single message for deletion at a time is very slow - it would be much faster to mark a batch of them all at once.

Comment: @jstedfast is there any other way to get the index for a `MimeMessage`? I'm using a `foreach` to loop through the messages within a folder, so I don't have an index in that case.

Comment: No. You'll need to maintain your own index offset.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey Nowadays the library (v 2.10.0.0) even more improved and you can write:
`inbox.AddFlags(uniqueId, MessageFlags.Deleted, true); // true = silent, no events thrown`